# Magento 2 add an attribute to product using rest

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, rest-api

I want to add an attribute to a product using rest api. I have created the attribute but not added to the product.

How can i add it to respective product using rest api?

Comment: How did You added the attribute to product @avesh

Comment: I created attribute in using store->attribute->product

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i found the solution.

```
           $data = array(
                "product" => array(
                    'custom_attributes' => array(
                        array( 'attribute_code' => 'useful',   
                           'value' => 1),
                    ),
                )
            );

            $apiClient->put("products/".$product->sku, $data);
```